# How to find closest table jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table, keyup, closest

I am trying to get the closest table when I search for a value.

This is my code but I always get 'undefined'.

jQuery :

```
 $(function() {
     $("#searchValue").keyup(function() {
         alert($(this).closest('table').attr('id'));
     });
 });
```

HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='searchValue' id='searchValue'/>

<table id='tablePlanning' class='tablesorter'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>PR Code</th>
            <th>Klant</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Project status</th>
            <th>Project Leader</th>
            <th>Coordinator</th>
            <th>Account manager</th>
            <th>Billing</th>
            <th>Start Datum</th>
            <th>Hardware</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: share your relevant HTML code...

Comment: to use `closest`, your table should be a `parent` from #searchValue

Comment: Assuming `$("#searchValue")` is inside a `<table>` element, the only explanation I can think of is that the table in question does not have an `id` attribute.

Comment: Your input is not inside the table so you can't use closest. Why not just use `.next('table')` or `siblings('table')` or `$('#tablePlanning')`?

Comment: In retrospect, maybe `closest()` wasn't the most appropriate name for a method that iterates over ancestors...

Answer (score 4):

Try to use **[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/)** to find the following `table` (at the same DOM level) instead :

```
$(function() {
   $("#searchValue").keyup(function() {
     alert($(this).next('table').attr('id'));
   });
});
```

`.closest()` is to find the first parent of the element.

But since your table has an `id`, you should use it (I hope you don't have several tables with the id `#tablePlanning` otherwise, you should use a classname.

Comment: To be specific, `closest()` matches the first element in the ancestor chain that matches the selector, *including the source element itself*.